# how to get index of a string in a sentence by php?

Tags: php

i have this code

```
<?php
$isi = $a['isi'];
$keyword = $_GET['tbSearch'];
$index = strpos("Ut varius consectetur tellus, id hendrerit neque auctor vel.","id");
echo "<h4>".$index."</h4>"          
?>
```

and the output is "30"

now, i have another code

```
<?php
$isi = $a['isi'];//from database
$keyword = $_GET['tbSearch'];//query string
$index = strpos($isi,$keyword);
echo "<h4>".$index."</h4>"          
?>
```

but the output is empty. any idea?

Comment: What is the value of `$a['isi']`? (not what it should be, but what it actually is returning)

Comment: What you have in `$isi` and `$keyword`?

Comment: echo $keyword and $isi

Comment: make a dump of $isi and $keyword!

Comment: $a['isi'] should be "Anda kenal dengan film kartun buatan Nickelodeon yang berjudul Avatar: The Last Airbender dan mengikutinya sampai sequel yang berjudul The Legend of Korra.Jika kalian suka dengan serial kartun The Legend of Korra, sudah sepantasnya kalian menunggu versi gamenya.
"

Comment: Again, not what it SHOULD be, what is it ACTUALLY

Comment: $_GET['tbSearch'] should be "korra". and when it echo $a['isi']."<br/>".$_GET['tbSearch']; it work!

Comment: You have to use `stripos` because it is case insensitive. `strpos` is case sensitive, so 'korra' won't find 'Korra', but stripos will.

Comment: $a['isi'] i get it from database!

Comment: Great, I posted it as an answer so others in the future will see.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you have to use [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) if you do not want to match the case, otherwise strpos will and it will return false.